# Why am I getting unwanted newline in my string?

Tags: python, file-io, newline, readline

This should be so simple, it's silly. But I can't get it to work.
I have a header which I define while reading a file:

```
    if "[gene=env]" in line or "[gene=HIV2gp7]" in line:
        header = line
```

now this header looks something like `">lcl|NC_001802.1_prot_NP_057856.1_8 [gene=env]"` I need to attach a number to it like so:
`">lcl|NC_001802.1_prot_NP_057856.1_8 [gene=env]1"`

I have 100 identical headers, which have to be numbered 1 through 100
But whatever I try, I can't get the number on the same line. The output is always

```
>lcl|NC_001802.1_prot_NP_057856.1_8 [gene=env]
1
>lcl|NC_001802.1_prot_NP_057856.1_8 [gene=env]
2
```

etc.

I've tried:

```
number = 0
    for item in randoms[group_name]:
        number+=1
        headerx = str(header)+str(number)
        print(headerx)
```

and countless other things, but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting your lines from a file using `readline` or `readlines` - if so, each line will end with a `\n` (newline) character. You need to strip those off:

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: Yup, that works, thanks. I wonder though why adding a `+ "\b"` at various places did nothing. Or why `end='' ` is only usable in so little places like `print`

Comment: Backspace character moves the cursor back one position, which doesn't help when you're already on a new line. Having an `end` parameter for `readline/s` would be nice, I agree. `str.splitlines` has `keepends` for the same purpose.